# make data-app-id configurable in yammer javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, yammer

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-app-id="*****************" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
```

i want to make data-app-id configurable not static. i am developing a SharePoint app part for yammer. my test and production networks are different so data-app-id for both the networks are different.is there any way that i can make it configurable so deploying on production i don't need to make change in code and i can put it in some property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. we can do something like this..

```
 yammerAppID = "***************";
    if (yammerAppID != "") {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js" data-app-id="' + yammerAppID + '"><\/script>');
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please configure Yammer AppID WebPart property.");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

one more best way is to use something like

// Set appId from querystring

yam.config({ appId: yourYamAppId });